# If I have only one creature in play, is it on a flank?

Tags: keyforge

Many cards (e.g. Valdr, Hand of Dis) reference creatures that are, or are not, on a/the flank. If I only have one creature in play, is it considered to be on a flank?

[image: Valdr - Valdr deals +2dmg while attacking an enemy creature on the flank.]
[image: Hand of Dis - Play: Destroy a creature that is not on a flank.]

Answer (score 9):

Yes. I'm including a screenshot of an e-mail reply from the developer on this topic.

> Flank simply means if its at the end of a battleline. If there is only
>   one creature in a battleline it is on both ends of a battleline and is
>   on both flanks.

[image]